What does "career sales" mean?
I read on https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Phats_%26_Small&oldid=1231722309:

The song debuted at number three in the UK Singles Chart, before climbing to number two, with career sales of this hit amassing them £5,000 in total due to their recording contract.

What does "career sales" mean? I don't know what career mean in that context. I read https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/career but that didn't help. Does that mean sales that took place over the group's entire career?

It looks like a misuse to me. An artist's "career sales" means the total sales value of that artist over their entire career. But songs don't have careers, so the cited usage is nonsense. On the other hand, the intended meaning is obvious - the relevant artist/band had a rubbish contract, so they only earned £5000 from that song (but I bet any money the actual sales were significantly more than that; the band don't normally get much of the sale price).

@FumbleFingers yeah it's so small so I thought that it may mean something else.

The fact that the song rose high in the charts means the total sales value must have been much higher than £5000 - unless it was sold for a ridiculously low price, which I seriously doubt.

@FumbleFingers now I understand wheat "fat and small" refers to.

That's Phats & Small - and neither of them are even "small", let alone "fat". They're just band member Jason Hayward's "stage name" and the surname of the other half of the duo, Russell Small. But obviously they didn't have a very good agent if they only earned £5k from an international hit.

That use of amass is somewhat odd, don't you think?  "...with career sales amassing them..."

It's written poorly from a stylistic point of view: Future releases featured his voice [Ben Ofoedu] but "Turn Around" featured Lee's voice Confusing! and … featuring the single "Sun Comes Out", this track sung by a returning Ofoedu and a new female vocalist, Carrie Luer. and a perfect example of a non sequitur "Small is a Brighton & Hove Albion F.C. fan after being taken to games as a youngster by his uncle." I mean, why is this of interest and in the end who cares?

The point is that despite high sales they got little money because the record company kept the rest of the money ("due to their recording contract"). That seems a common enough story in the pop music industry. "Amass" indicates that this is the total accrued over their career.

@FumbleFingers It's not saying that the total sales were  £5000. It's saying that the artist only received that much in royalty payments.

@Barmar: That's what it means (or at least, is intended to mean). But what it says is just nonsense if interpreted literally.

anyone wants to add an answer?

@FumbleFingers It's important that it says "amassing them" rather than just "amassing". This means it's describing what went to them, not what the total sales were.

@Barmar: okay, point taken. But it's very poor phrasing, and we shouldn't defend it here. The fact that it wasn't even understood at all by the querent is surely proof of that. Obviously I don't know the exact wording of the contract, but i doubt it meaningfully gave the band some tiny fraction of the sale price after some low total sale value, so I'm guessing it was somehow time-limited, in which case "career sales" would be a silly way to describe it.

@FumbleFingers It's Wikipedia, go ahead and fix it if you think the wording is poor.

"career sales" means "total sales during their career".
Qualifying this with "of this hit" means it's only referring to the sales of the one song mentioned, "Turn Around".
"amassing them £5,000 in total" means that they only received a total of £5,000 in payments, even though it was a big hit. Maybe the contract specified a flat payment, or an extremely small percentage of sales. As new artists, they didn't have the clout necessary to negotiate better terms.
